# "You have that power too"

Tags: internal-consistency, society, magic

In the "Star Wars: The Force Awakens" teaser trailer two, Luke Skywalker says:

> "The Force is strong in my family. My father had it. My sister has it. You have that power too..."

So how will the universe change when a means of letting anyone access the powers of The Force becomes available, rather than a few sensitive people who study and train for decades to become Jedi or Sith? (I mean the social, political and economic universe. While trillions of sentient beings could potentially rearrange the physical galaxy using the Force, this would require an extreme level of organization not being contemplated at this time).

It does not matter if you are part of the Empire, the Rebellion or live on an isolated planet that is not involved in the conflict, so long as you are a sentient being, with some relatively simple method you can access the power of The Force. Like all powers and skills, you still need some training or instruction to understand all the aspects of The Force ("The Force for Dummies"), and if you spend more time practicing, you get better at the attributes you do understand.

There will be a bell curve of ability, with a very few on the left tail who simply do not understand or have the ability to access The Force, and a right tail where the Jedi masters reside, but the bulk of the population now understands what The Force is and can manipulate it for their own ends.

Comment: Decades? Skywalkers train for a couple weeks and get everything they need.

Comment: Yoda and Obi Wan were both very clear that training Luke to become a Jedi will take a long time, and Yoda even believed that Luke was too old to begin Jedi training in "The Empire Strikes Back". It is also clear that the Skywalkers are somehow flawed in their ability to master the Force, perhaps because their training was abbreviated.

Comment: George, you sold the franchise to Disney, so down voting the question is too little, too late. Why not just come out and explain why the question is being downvoted?

Comment: Upvoted the question. Under no way it should be downvoted by rationale beings. It is a legit question.

Comment: Is this something which has happened in the new movie - (anybody can learn), or is this a world-building question just asking what *would* happen if anybody could learn? I would guess the downvote is because for someone who isn't familiar with Star Wars, there isn't a clear separation between the Star Wars world, and how/whether you are changing it and asking about that change or whether you're just asking, "what happens next" for a movie.

Comment: It's probably being downvoted because it probably belongs in Fantasy and Sci Fi more than worldbuilding (I think the Star Wars universe is an existing, "built" world).  I understand that the question asker is asking about a change to that world, but I'm not sure that counts as building a new world...of existing IP.

Comment: You have to define what the Force is ...which Star Wars has redone over and over from its origin as a woozy mystic feeling that gave vague hints and sensations in the early movies to the cartoon fly/float/lightning bolt throwing crap of the prequels to god knows what the EU has done with it.

Comment: Training? Practice? You don't have time for that. That's the old way to use the force, Luke. Today you can drink the force in a glass of probiotic kefir with cultures of Lactobacillus and Midi-chlorians. If you are constipated or feeling low on the force then don't journey light-years to sit in a swamp to listen to some creepy muppet drone on about motivational life-coaching bull-shit. Now you can feel the force and enjoy a healthy colon by going no further than your local spacemart to pick up a delicious Sithsastion's Kefir. You need the force, not some loser in a swamp.

Comment: As I understand it, *everyone* in the Star Wars universe has some force ability. (barring species with specific anti-force exclusions).. But for the extreme vast majority of people that access is so small as to just provide life, and the occasional feeling of "being watched", or "deja vu", or "animal magnetism", or "gut feeling". Which are all very very weak manipulations of the Force. Even us regular humans seem to do such things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the most part, I think things would stay the same. The Force is a known entity, so cultures shouldn't have to shift much to accept it. Leaders should still lead, followers should still follow. Technology is still useful (even Luke Skywalker couldn't have gotten anywhere without his X-Wing and R2D2), and most jobs should still exist (someone still has to clean the toilets). However, there are some changes I can think of:

People like the Jedi will now be in high demand, but as teachers rather than peacekeepers. They can either accept this change and start teaching for massive profits, or stay secluded and let other people figure things out on their own. Either way, there will eventually be a lot of jobs and resources for teaching the Force.

There are races in Star Wars that are naturally immune to some Force effects: if these exist in your galaxy, these races will now be greatly sought after for pretty much any job.

Assuming robots still can't access the Force, there might be a shift in the labor force from synthetics to organics (or perhaps 'naturals', since some natural life may not be organic). This could have profound effects on the individual level, but overall it shouldn't change much; some people will get jobs that wouldn't have, others will be forced into more menial tasks as robots are specialized for 'thinking' jobs.

There will also be a very interesting transitional period where everyone tries to cheat everyone else. The most industrious life forms may be able to mind-trick their way to the top before anyone realizes what's going on, others may begin training Force-wielding soldiers for an edge on the battlefield. Like the Germans in the early days of WWI, some will take advantage of these new powers; others will do what they've always done, and lose a lot (maybe even everything) for it.

So there'll be a terrifying time of upheaval, followed by a galaxy that looks very different on the individual level, but basically the same on the macro level. It's pretty much impossible to get any more specific without investigating dozens of possibilities.

Comment: Interesting answer. I'm hoping for more people to chime and maybe looking at some of those possibilities before selecting an answer, but you have made some good points about the possible changes at the macro level.

Comment: @Thucydides I also hope you get more answers, I'd like to read them :)